# Unprotected Knockout in Flourescent Light

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I'm repairing an old flourescent fixture and noticed the original line wires pass through a 2 1/4" knockout that isn't protected by anything like a bushing.

Is this just the way it was certified?  Or can I find a 2 1/4" bushing for that?

[image]

Comment: Who said it was certified?  Might just be poor workmanship that did not bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some patient web searching and a 24-hour delay for delivery, I was able to find and install the needed bushing.

[image]

For reference, I ended up at mcmaster.com under Hardware > Grommets > Locking Grommets.

I am grateful for Harper's knowledge and input here.  For an old UL-listed fixture still in its original condition, the lack of wire protection might be normal.

However, the UL approved instructions for the modern retrofit kit stated, "Warning - To prevent wire abrasion, do not expose wiring to edges of sheet metal or other sharp objects."  I take this to mean that the bushing is now required for compliance, for a workmanlike result, and for peace of mind.  For that reason specifically, I believe this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is an awful lot of black and white wires.

I can't quite tell if there is a junction box in the ceiling behind the hole.  Maybe.

What I do see is that the black and white wires do not have markings on them, which means they are Romex cable, and not THHN wires coming out of conduit. No sheath can be seen anywhere.  That would suggest a junction box, because typically when pulled into a junction box, the sheath is stripped off except for the mandatory 1/4" on the inside of the cable clamp.

If there is a junction box above this opening, then that is fine.

It's perfectly common for fixtures to be UL-Listed to be mounted square-on to a junction box, with a big opening like this for the wires which must fully overlap the junction box. (need not be centered, but not a half-moon with some box some drywall).  Remember all fixtures that are UL, CSA or ETL rated have been inspected to assure compliance with the UL White Book design standard.  If the opening needed a bushing, UL would have required that.

If there is no junction box there, and that's "just ceiling void" up there, that's a huge problem. You must retrofit a junction box there, with the sheath coming into the box the required amount etc.

Comment: Yes, it's 14-2 NM cable and yes there's a light box in the ceiling.  Someone ran the 4 line wires for the ballasts up in there, and then left the cable conductors dangling out a bit.  That's not how I'd do it.  For a dry location like this, it will be more convenient to have the nuts in the fixture and only the three wires pass through.

I found a source for 2-1/4" bushings online.  I'm going to try that and follow up with the results.

Comment: @Robert I don't see how bushings will help you, if they were required to render the wires safe, then UL would have required them. Every fixture must be built to the UL White Book standards and be installed according to instructions that UL has approved which comply with NEC.  I am more concerned with "no junction box back there" - if no box, you must pull down the fixture and install one.

Comment: Understood, and to add a twist here, I'm looking at a UL-labeled retrofit kit with installation instructions that state, "Warning - To prevent wire abrasion, do not expose wiring to edges of sheet metal or other sharp objects."